# jquery Form validation for Housenumber

Tags: jquery, regex

How to validate the below Housenumber using jquery Form validation?

```
1
1b
12
12b
123
123b
1234
1234b
```

the letter should be always last position , but not required. Please help me to create regular expression.

Comment: What have you tried so far? http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good start for learning regular expressions. It will help you even beyond this particular problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following RegExp will do:

```
/^\d+[a-zA-Z]*$/
```

- `^` *Must start with*
- `\d+` *Any number* (`\d`), *at least once* (`+`)
- `[a-zA-Z]*` Some letters `[a-zA-Z]` (optional: `*`)
- `$` *Must end here*

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have updated RegExp /^\d+[a-zA-Z]{0,1}$/ and it works fine.

Comment: @Chauhan `{0,1}` can also be written as `?`.

Comment: Instead of `{0,1}` just use `?`

Answer (score 2):

regex `"^\\d+/?\\d*[a-zA-Z]?(?<!/)$"` will match numbers like:

- 67
- 67/33
- 67/33a
- 67a
- 67/a

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if wrong. String can can not end with two more digits.
In this case "\d+[a-zA-Z]?" should work